# Laravel infinite loop

Tags: laravel-4

I'm building an app using Laravel v.4.2. In the `app/public` directory, I have `images` folder which contains static images. Then, I created an `ImagesController` for users to manage assets. However, when I entered the URL: `myapp.dev/images` into browser, I got an infinite redirect loop error. I double checked all my routes and noticed there're no ones related to `images` path. Even when I commented out all routes entries, the error still exists.

I found a work around to this by rename the controller, however this is not going to be an ideal solution.

What can I do to completely deal with this error?

Comment: That sounds weird... what's in your `.htaccess` file? (in the public directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to rename either your `images` directory, or your `images` route. What's happening is expected behavior of your server: when it hits the `public` directory (which is where all Laravel requests begin), it's finding that the `images` folder exists, so your URL is not redirected to `index.php` and your application is not launched. So it never even gets to your routes.

---

The cause of the loop itself depends on the contents of your `.htaccess` file, but it is probably happening because when you request `myapp.dev/images`, your server recognizes that `images` is a directory and immediately returns a 301 redirect to `myapp.dev/images/` (with the trailing `/`). Then, your `.htaccess` file jumps in and tries to convert it back to `myapp.dev/images`, without the trailing slash. This happens in the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`.

Normally, when navigating to a folder in `app/public`, you should get a **403 Forbidden** error. The line that does this is `Options -Indexes`, which disables the ability to display a list (or index) of directories in the browser. Usually, you have indexes disabled server-wide, in your server's `httpd.conf` file. You might want to check that that's the case—or at the very least, add `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess` file in `app/public`.

Also, make sure that your `.htaccess` file in `app/public` contains *both* of these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: then why did the infinite loop occur?

Comment: Probably because of your server behavior fighting with your `.htaccess` over trailing slashes. Take a look at the edited answer.